# How to detect GPS status through adb shell?

Tags: adb, gps, shell, android-emulator, scripts

I need to detect **GPS status** through `adb shell`. I have tried `dumpsys location` command but the **output of this command is not changed** when the GPS is enabled/disabled.

Comment: Did you try the [solution here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/currest-gps-status-in-android-with-appium/17527/3)?  If it works will post as an answer

Comment: Which Android version and device?

Comment: See if `adb shell settings get secure location_providers_allowed` works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Firelord, works like a charm. I'd like to mark your comment as the correct answer if you post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
adb shell settings get secure location_providers_allowed
```

Possible outcomes:

- returns nothing, implying the GPS is switched off.
- `gps,wifi,network` or `gps,network` -- High accuracy mode
- `wifi,network` or `network` only -- Battery saving mode
- `gps` -- Device only